# ETA for Expo-payments-stripe for managed workflow

Tags: react-native, expo

Does anyone know what the ETA (expected time of release) of the Expo-payment-stripe for managed workflow? This information helps in project planning and using the right solutions for our product. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work on Expo. It will take at least a few more months, and possibly longer, for us to integrate Stripe into the managed workflow, as is.

The reason for this is that Apple will sometimes reject apps if they have any Stripe code in them but aren't collecting payments, and right now, all managed workflow apps have the same binary code.

For now, the bare workflow is the best way to integrate Stripe and other payments solutions. In the medium term, we are working on ways to give you the best of both worlds. And eventually, we'll probably be able to put it into something that looks like the managed workflow.

I'm sorry we don't have a better solution for you already. This is one of the most requested features and we are working on stuff now that will give you more options to solve it in good ways.

Comment: A follow-up (stupid) question: Since we are using stripe payment to accept payment, does that mean that we can use expo-payment-stripe in managed workflow, or that just simply would not work? Thanks!